# Wordpress - Loop of posts displays the posts in a scattered manner

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have a simple problem regarding how my Wordpress blog displays the posts in the loop.
Apparently the loop scatters the posts in different directions.

Please take a look at the main page on http://pavilionmagazine.org and see for yourself. The first (last in the loop) post at the bottom is not displayed correctly.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you could start by posting the Loop's code.

Comment: `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?><?php /* The loop */ ?>
   <?php
   $n=0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    //$n++;
    //if($n!=5) {
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    //} else {
    //get_template_part( 'content-banner', get_post_format() );
    //}
    ?>
   <?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Is this a problem with how the posts are appearing on the webpage, or is the loop not echoing out the correct content on the page. From what I can see, the content is there, but it appears that the post containers are all different heights due to varying content. Is that the problem? Do you just want them to all appear the same height and show up in a nice grid?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, it might just be from containers of different heights due to varying content. And yes, I would like the posts to show up in a nice grid. The content of the loop is there on the page, but it's not displaying the posts in a nice grid.

Comment: If you simply want all of them to be the same height, just set .post to height:600px; or whatever you feel is an appropriate height. That will make the containers all the same size, and they will appear in an even grid. However after you do that, you'd need to adjust where/how elements appear inside of the container. Because the content for each post will always be different, you will have varying image sizes, and varying paragraph lengths. So you need to pick where the margins/padding will be, and how they will look. I can give advice on how I think it should look, but it's up to you.

Comment: What I would recommend, is focusing on getting all of the images to be the same sizes, and the excerpts to be the same length. That way the posts will appear to be similar regardless of what their content happens to be.

Comment: I've tried making the images the same size and it does fix the issue. However I would like to find a solution inside css or html. Anyway, thanks for replying to my question and for giving me solutions.

Comment: I made all the images the same size, the .post height is 500px (Developer Tools plugin Chrome, so I can preview), but on mouse hover the forth post, it scatters the posts again. And it even makes the footer dissapear and go into the middle of the page. So difficult to make this simple loop work.

Comment: The problem now is with the title's length. Sometime it uses a couple of lines more.